# How to use WebView with dynamically created HTML

Tags: cocoa, webview

I have an app that creates HTML pages and displays them in a `WebView`. That part works great.

My app has controls that allow the user to view different data. I can load a new HTML string into the `WebView`. Again, that works fine.

I have two related questions: First, my dynamically created HTML pages contain references to images in `<img>` tags that are actually compressed and stored locally in a proprietary file. I can load these into some kind of Cocoa image object on request, or I can decompress them into a file and allow `WebView` to load them. The latter is probably straightforward but I'm looking for a way to implement the former. I think I need to respond/react to the `webView:resource:willSendRequest:redirectResponse:fromDataSource:` message to hand `WebView` an image somehow. Any hints?

Second, if the user selects a link, I need to intercept the handling of the link and deal with it myself. I may simply scroll the user to a location on the same page if the link actually references a location on the page, or (more frequently) I will want to load an entirely different page -- again, created dynamically by my app and loaded as a string into the `WebView` using `loadHtmlString:baseUrl:`. I'd like to simply be notified of the URL so that I can decide what to do with it (as I am with UIWebView in iOS) but I'm not sure of the best/easiest way to do that.

I'm lumping these questions together because there may be a general way of looking at this entire problem that I'm missing. For example, it seems like there should be a way to supersede the normal page loading process so that `WebView` asks my app for the bytes it would normally go to the Web to request. The impression I get is that `WebView` does its own thing and only *advises* me that it is loading a page/resource from the Web. I need it to actually request the data from me.

Answer (score 2):

The best approach is to implement your own subclass of `NSURLProtocol` that can return the resources you need.  That way you can use you own internal URLs and the URL loading system will fetch them by invoking methods on your `NSURLProtocol` subclass.

It’s really quite easy to do this; you need to implement `+canInitWithRequest:` to check for your special URL scheme, e.g.

```
+ (BOOL)canInitWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
{
  NSString *scheme = [[request URL] scheme];
  return [scheme caseInsensitiveCompare:@"app"] == NSOrderedSame;
}
```

then make your `-startLoading` method return the correct data, for instance:

```
- (void)startLoading
{
  NSURLRequest *req = [self request];
  id<NSURLProtocolClient> client = [self client];
  NSCachedURLResponse *cachedResponse = [self cachedResponse];

  if (cachedResponse) {
    [client URLProtocol:self cachedResponseIsValid:cachedResponse];
    return;
  }

  // support app:blank
  if ([[[req URL] resourceSpecifier] isEqualToString:@"blank"]) {
    NSData *data = [NSData data];

    NSURLResponse *response
      = [[NSURLResponse alloc] initWithURL:[req URL]
                                  MIMEType:@"text/html"
                     expectedContentLength:[data length]
                          textEncodingName:@"UTF-8"];

    [client URLProtocol:self
     didReceiveResponse:response
     cacheStoragePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed];

    [client URLProtocol:self didLoadData:data];

    [client URLProtocolDidFinishLoading:self];
    return;
  }

  // Not found
  NSError *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:NSURLErrorDomain
                                       code:NSURLErrorFileDoesNotExist
                                   userInfo:nil];

  [client URLProtocol:self didFailWithError:error];
}
```